# use subdomain on different host

Tags: dns, 301-redirect

I want to accomplish something that I thought was simple. My wish is as follows:
I have a domainname with hosting, a WordPress multisite (with subfolder setup) installed and running: gangleri.nl.
I have another domain *at another host and without hosting*: monas.nl

I created a subdomain on gangleri.nl: monas.gangleri.nl and the domain redirects to that subdomain.

Now what I want is to have monas.nl act like a website, not a website in a subdomain. I would like to have post urls as in monas.nl/posttitle.

I first thought to do this with the DNS settings of Monas.nl. I now have an URL forward, CURL is not what I want and I did not manage to get A-records or CNAMEs to work.

I tried using the htaccess file of the WP installation in monas.gangleri.nl. I tried 301, rewrite and whatnot, but also without success.

Meanwhile, I have been reading so much that I no longer have a clue what to do. A-record doesn't sound probable, since I have no IP for the subdomain, so an A-record would point to gangleri.nl rather than using the subdomain. 
Also I have no idea if I should do something in the DNS settings of gangleri.nl or monas.nl, both, one of them and something somewhere else.
I have the idea that I've tried everything, but the more I try and read about it, the less I can get my head around. People talking about A-records to subdomains while I can only use IPs, CNAME settings that my host doesn't support or something.

Could somebody tell me if what I want is possible and if so, take me by the hand and guide me through it?

Comment: Somebody on the Dutch WordPress forum adviced to me make a wildcard domain in httpd.conf and then adding a domain mapping plugin. Now I've been trying to find out for a couple of days what a wildcard domain is, she explicitly said: not wildcard subdomain.

Comment: Hm, look first, talk later. I can't even find the httpd.conf file. I do have a folder names /conf (same level as /httpdocs), but I'm not even allowed to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The A Record has to be set to the IP address of your WordPress installation, i.e. 83.137.194.17.

Then ask your web host to add an entry for this domain in its `httpd-vhosts.conf` pointing at the directory of your current domain `gangleri.nl`. And then you install the [domain mapper plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) ([tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/)) and let WordPress do the rest.

By the way: There is [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) where you may ask more questions if you get stuck again.